# Recursion with access to prior variables/nested list comprehension

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, logic

**Disclaimer**: I am not a computer scientist, I have no formal computer science training (currently enrolled in my first CS course ever), and I have known Haskell for 2 months. Always had a love for tinkering with source code (C++ for 2 years in high school, MATLAB in undergraduate).

The **short version** of the question I have is:

What is the closest Haskell equivalent of nested for loops that give an *equivalent* amount of flexibility?

I know the question has been asked many many times and the usual answer always is that list comprehension is the best bet. But this assumes that I know how many lists I have; what if I don’t?

In a nested for loop for example, I have access to the the outer loops variables; and to some extend in a list comprehension, I do too; **however** I think we need to know exactly how many `<-` binds we need to do apriori (in some ways this i think this is true of the for loops as well..i mean we do have to know how deep to nest..right? -- too many years of imperative or OOP programming.)

The usual solution when you don’t know how many elements are there is recursion with a well founded base case. But in this case we lose access to the the earlier stack variables. So what's the fix?

Now I know this question is too vague to be answered without some concrete example.

So here is the **long version**.

I am building a simple logic puzzle parser/solver that can solve puzzles of the form over at: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/

I did a first attempt using Lazy Maps where I filtered the solution space myself; obviously this has efficiency problems and the program does not terminate for a large problem set. You can see this at: https://github.com/iabraham/logicpuzzleparser-simple

On the other hand why re-invent the wheel? So drawing inspiration from: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle#Haskell

I built my own ADTs and made them monads and all that (probably breaking a few laws in between) to use list comprehension-esque methods. Attaching a proof of concept:

```
module Main where

import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.List           as L
import qualified Data.Map            as M
import           Debug.Trace

data Property a = Property String a deriving (Show, Eq)
data Properties a = Properties String [a] deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor (Property) where
  fmap f (Property name prop) = Property name (f prop)

instance Functor (Properties) where
  fmap f (Properties name prop) = Properties name (map f prop)

instance Applicative (Properties) where
  pure a = Properties "" [a]
  (Properties _ f) <*> (Properties _ b) = Properties "" (f <*> b)

instance Alternative (Properties) where
  empty = Properties "" []
  (Properties n1 v1) <|> (Properties n2 v2) = Properties (n1++n2) (v1++v2)

instance Monad (Properties) where
  return = pure
  (Properties _ prop) >>= f = Properties "" (aux f prop) where
    aux _ []     = []
    aux g (x:xs) = xss ++ aux g xs where
      Properties _ xss = g x

data ClueExp = AlphaExp String String
  | OmegaExp String String
  | AtPosExp Int String String
  | NotAtPosExp Int String String
  | LeftOfExp String String String String
  | DirLeftOfExp String String String String
  | EquivExp String String String String
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Exp = ClueExp
  | DefExp String [String]
  | SolExp
  | QuitExp
  deriving (Show, Eq)

myPerms :: Property [a] -> Properties [a]
myPerms p@(Property name _) = Properties name permlist where
  Property _ permlist = fmap L.permutations p

color = Property "Color" ["Blue", "Green", "Red"]
nation= Property "Nation" ["Brazillian", "German", "Australian"]
animal= Property "Animal"["Dogs", "Cats", "Fishes"]
sport = Property "Sport" ["Basketball", "Soccer", "Football"]

c1 = AtPosExp 2 "Nation" "Brazillian"
c2 = OmegaExp "Nation" "German"
c3 = AlphaExp "Animal" "Dog"
c4 = AtPosExp 2 "Animal" "Fishes"
c5 = OmegaExp "Sport" "Football"
c6 = NotAtPosExp 2 "Sport" "Soccer"
c7 = AlphaExp "Color" "Green"
c8 = OmegaExp "Color" "Red"


clues = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8]

propEnv = [sport,color,nation,animal]

solution = solve propEnv clues

solve (p@(Property name prop):ps) cs =
  do
    x <- myPerms p
    eval x cs []
    (solve ps cs ) <|> (return x)
    where
      eval ls (c:cs) usedvar = case c of
        (AlphaExp list item) -> case (list == name) of
          True  -> guard (head ls == item) >> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
          False -> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
        (OmegaExp list item) -> case (list == name) of
          True  -> guard (last ls == item) >> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
          False -> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
        (AtPosExp n list item) -> case (list == name) of
          True -> let η p = (\x -> head (iterate tail x) !! p) in
           (guard (η (n-1) ls == item)) >> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
          False -> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
        (NotAtPosExp n list item) -> case (list == name) of
          True -> let η p = (\x -> head (iterate tail x) !! p) in
           (guard (η (n-1) ls /= item)) >> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
          False -> eval ls cs (name:usedvar)
      eval ls [] vars = return ()
solve [] cs = return ["Zilch"]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World"
```

As you might have guessed the problem is for *equivalence expressions* and all kinds of expressions involving two lists. Recursion denies me access to them, and list comprehension requires me to know in advance how many `Property` expressions the user is going to give my program.

Any ideas/hints/advice?

Comment: I fail to see how you would get access to the outer loop variables in a language like Java if you don't know how deeply you'll need to nest. You'd still have to use recursion in that case, no?

Comment: Oh, so you're trying to write `solve` without recursion?  I dunno, I mean I guess you could use `foldM` but I don't see a problem with how you've done it.

Comment: The problem is with equivalence expressions; these are clues of the form "The Brazilian lives in the Blue house." So to implement this constraint you need access to both the Nation list and the Color list. There are details over at: https://github.com/iabraham/logicpuzzleparser-simple/tree/master/report

Some clues require you to interact with two lists

Comment: Recursion is the analogue of for loops. I sense the zebra puzzles are not essential to the question you are trying to ask. Can you come up with a trivial example that demonstrates the issue of interacting with two lists?

Comment: And add some actual code in an imperative language which displays the kind of thing you feel unable to do in Haskell right now!

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this answer is half-serious. I don't really recommend writing Haskell code this way, but hopefully it'll provide some insight into the possibilities the language actually brings to the table. When solving problems that suggest an imperative approach, most often you can actually find a neater, functional way to solve them.*

---

Ironically, Haskell already has a "loop"; it's called `forM`.

```
forM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m (t b)
```

It's closer to the for-each concept, though, since it takes a `Traversable`. It can be executed in an arbitrary context, though. When people used to older style of programming say "a for loop" they typically think about a loop that goes over a numeric indices list. This is easy enough:

```
main = forM_ [1..10] print
```

At this point people would complain about lacking the ability to break out of it and do all kinds of weird manipulations. To allow that and more contrived expressions, you need to make the loop depend on the monadic expression itself:

```
realForM :: Monad m => (m Bool) -> m () -> m ()
```

If you wanted to provide "slots" for the init and increment, you could do that as well:

```
realForM :: Monad m =>
       a                 -- starting value
    -> (StateT a m Bool) -- end condition
    -> (StateT a m ())   -- increment (state change)
    -> (a -> m ())       -- action to perform repeatedly
    -> m ()              -- ends up in one action
```

Use like any other loop!

```
realForM
  (0 :: Int)
  ((== 10) <$> get)
  (modify (+1)) $ \x -> do
      -- your loop body here
```

Even without implementing it, it's not hard to see that nesting is entirely possible:

```
realForM (0 :: Int) ((< 4) <$> get) (modify (+1)) $ \x ->
    realForM (0 :: Int) ((< 4) <$> get) (modify (+1)) $ \y -> do
        putStrLn $ show x ++ ", " ++ show y
```

However, this still doesn't allow you to modify `x` from the inner loop, since the `State` is entirely hidden from the loop body! To allow that, we need to expose the loop body to the entire state with the counter, allowing it to modify it:

```
realForM' :: Monad m =>
       a                 -- starting value
    -> (StateT a m Bool) -- end condition
    -> (StateT a m ())   -- action to perform repeatedly
    -> m ()
```

This way, we can actually get rid of the rather unnecessary increment parameter and just do the increment at the end of the loop body (This makes the implementation really neat; see below!):

```
realForM' (0 :: Int) ((< 10) <$> get) $ 
    realForM' (0 :: Int) ((< 3) <$> get) $ do
        y <- get
        x <- lift get            
        lift . lift . putStrLn $ show x ++ ", " ++ show y

        modify (+1)
        lift $ modify (+1)
```

As you can see, the nested state is clearly accessible. I suppose that's what you wanted all along.

If **specifying the nesting levels explicitely seems problematic**, you can use tagged `MonadState`-like contexts to traverse the stack implicitly, or go back to the original implementation, but pass some references (eww) like `TVar` instead.

---

Implementations:

```
realForM i end inc a = do
    flip evalStateT i $ do
        whileM_ end $ do 
            x <- get
            lift $ a x
            inc

realForM' i end a = flip evalStateT i $ whileM_ end a
```

The `whileM_` helper is a part of `Control.Monad.Loops` package, but I typically just copy this one because I find it the most useful in practice:

```
whileM_ :: (Monad m) => m Bool -> m a -> m ()
whileM_ p f = go
    where go = do
            x <- p
            if x
                then f >> go
                else return ()
```